# Java: Compare Scanner Input Array to Random Generated Array

Tags: java, arrays

I looked through the website and saw similar posts but need some further clarification. As usual, new to Java and would like some assistance. The scenario is a Lotto program. Input your numbers into array 1, Array 2 generates random numbers. Compare your input to random array. Currently stuck on comparing my input to the random array and printing out how many numbers were correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class Lotto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

{
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean isNumber;
      int[] numbers = new int[6];
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
               do{   
                    if (input.hasNextInt()) 
                    {    
                        System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
                            for (int h = 0; h < 5; h++)
                            numbers[h] = input.nextInt();
                            isNumber = true;
                    } else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not a valid input!");
                        isNumber = false;
                        input.next();
                    }

                }  while (!(isNumber));

                    for (int h = 0; h < numbers.length; h++)
                     System.out.print(numbers[h] + " ");      

                        {

                                    int[] lottery = new int[6];
                                    int randomNum;

                                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                                    {
                                        randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 50); 
                                        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
                                        {
                                            if (lottery[i] == randomNum) 
                                            {
                                                randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 50);
                                            }

                                        }
                                        lottery[i] = randomNum;
                                    }

                                    for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++)
                                        System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
                        }
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to the end:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < lottery.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == lottery[j]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + counter);
```

change first for-loop from `for (int h = 0; h < 5; h++)` to `for (int h = 0; h <= 5; h++)` and creater the counter variable

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.